# Retrieve a set of multiple nodes from an XML document using XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, jdbc, ready-api

I'm working in readyAPI, i have an xml response from a JDBC request like :

```
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="10">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <ID_Question>72</ID_Question>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="2">
         <ID_Question>73</ID_Question>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="3">
         <ID_Question>74</ID_Question>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="4">
         <ID_Question>75</ID_Question>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="5">
         <ID_Question>76</ID_Question>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

i want to retrieve all the `ID_Question` elements as a list to use them in a rest request

i tried the property transfer using the XPath like this :

`//*:ID_Question`

but it returns only the first value.

What should i use to retrieve all the values?

Thanks for help !

Comment: The XPath looks OK so presumably there's something about the way you are using readyAPI. Please show a complete code example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your xpath seems to indicate that the actual xml includes namespaces, but your sample xml doesn't show them. Please edit the question and add a short, well formed, representative sample of your xml.